# What does "Attero Dominatus" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-translation

"Attero Dominatus" is the title of an album and song by the band Sabaton. According to [this](http://www.cosmosgaming.com/music/music-reviews/sabaton-attero-dominatus/) article, which does not cite any source, it means "destroy tyranny", according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attero_Dominatus) Wikipedia page it means "I destroy tyrannies". The band has not provided an official translation of the song. What is the correct translation?

Comment: As the song is talking about armies defeating the 3rd Reich, the meaning is quite easy...

Comment: @sabaton, which is what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The official translation is off.
I am rather annoyed that people put time and money into projects like this but do not take more care with the translation of a name — but I refrain from ranting further.

Let us start with the verb *atterere*.
It means literally something like "to rub against", and it also has the sense "to destroy".
Perhaps "to destroy by rubbing" is a good overall translation.
Check [the dictionary entry in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=attero&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for more detail.
There would be far better verbs for destroying tyranny, but asking for them should be taken to a separate question.
If we pick the translation "to destroy" for *atterere*, the form *attero* means indeed "I destroy".

I see two ways to parse *dominatus*:

1. It can be [the noun *dominatus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=dominatus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), which means many kinds of rule or sovereignty.
   It does cover tyranny as well, but I would not recognize it as the principal meaning.
   In the context of the short sentence *attero dominatus*, it appears to be in the plural accusative, which indeed happens to look like the singular nominative (the basic form given in a dictionary) for this word.
   This leads to translation possibilities like these:

   > *Attero dominatus.*
   >   I weaken/destroy sovereignties.
   >   I wear out the rules. (≈ I defy the law and break it slowly.)
2. It can be a participle of the verb [*dominari*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DD%3Aentry+group%3D50%3Aentry%3Ddominor), "to rule".
   This leads to translation possibilities like these:

   > *Attero dominatus.*
   >   After having been a ruler I rub something.
   >   I rule and destroy.

As always, there is no unique correct translation without more precise context.
And I admit that some of the suggested translations are quite nonsensical, but I would argue that so is the original phrase, to some extent at least.
The official translation is a possible direction, but the choices of words look unnatural to me.

Answer (score 4):

*attero, atterere, attrivi, attritum*, to grind down, wear away, etc., often implying persistence.

*dominatus*, 4th decl., here the accusative plural to form the object of the verb.

I'd say that it simply means 'I batter away against tyrannies' (or some equivalent verb).