# Is "Attero Denarios" correct for "I destroy coins"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am writing a series and looking for a title particularly in Latin. Got the idea from Sabaton's 'Attero Dominatus' and have read [that thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5755/79).
'Attero Denarios', seems be correct for 'I destroy coins' or 'I weaken coins'. But open for correctness or something better.
For coins is short for cryptocurrency coins, so is of the cyber realm.

Comment: A denarius is a specific coin; you'd want *nummus* (acc. pl. *nummos*). *Attero* is also a weird verb to use.

Comment: Yeah... nummus though correct just doesn't sound fitting, especially to a person not knowing Latin. For example,  seems like related to being numb.

Answer (score 3):

As denarius is a specific coin and and *atterere* only means destroying in the sense of rubbing, *attero denarios* would mean primarily something like "I rub dimes against each other" and can be stretched to "I ruin dimes by rubbing them".
In order to give an impression of the tone, I translated *denarius* to "dime" just because they are both specific coins; the two coins are unrelated.

My answer to the question is no: *attero denarios* is not correct for "I destroy coins".
The words have meanings in the right general direction, but they don't add up to a good translation.
[Be careful with what you consider synonyms.](https://xkcd.com/2352/)

The most straightforward way to say "I destroy coins" is ***nummos deleo***.
The word *nummus* is a general word for a coin, and *delere* is good general word for destroying.
(It is not the only verb for destroying; see [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/13653/79) for a list or consult [any good online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).)

In a comment you objected to *nummus* as it sounds a bit like the English "numb".
Such coincidences happen when translating between languages, and I don't see any reason to be alarmed unless it suggests something particularly obscene or counterproductive.
If you want to worry about such things, you need to know your target audience's languages (not only English!) and have several experts help you out.
I see nothing wrong with using *nummus*.

Comment: *Deleo* is off course fine; if you are looking for other choices for "destroy," Latin does not let you down; I recommend [this old answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/how-do-you-say-this-phrase-in-latin-venisti-vedisti-you-destroyed/13653#13653) of mine.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Good point! I added that and a dictionary link for more breadth in vocabulary.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it has given me something to chew on for my long drive. I think I can see how it may look to have more than one meaning.  As is for, destroying coins, but also as, numerous destruction, kind of playing off it as a pun in a way. I do like when a title may appear to have more than one meaning.   I do agree rubbing coins doesn't sound right when translated, just seems to sound decent.   I may go with Nummos Destruo.... or similar,  Nummo Destruo, Nummos Destruos... or just as it was stated. Got to think on it. Thanks!

Comment: @MrPatrick I'm glad to be able to help! *Destruo* is certainly a possible verb. Regarding forms of the noun: Use either *nummos* (plural) or *nummum* (singular) but not other forms like *nummo*. If you use other cases than accusative, you get things like "I destroy with coins" or "I destroy for coins" or "I am a coin and I destroy". Also, I recommend taking a look at [our quick tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) at some point to see more functionalities.

Comment: Thanks again. If I ever write a satire, I would definitely go with "I rub dimes." Or, "I am a coin and I destroy" (Translated)